# List find and replace

Tags: python, list

Given the following list of elements:

> tmp = ['T', 'h', 'e', '/', ' * ', 's', 'k', 'y', ' * ', 'i', 's', '/', '/', 'b', 'l', 'u', 'e']

I want to :

1. Replace '*' or '/' by a single space
2. In case of two consecutive occurrences of '*' or '/', replace those two occurrences by a single space and convert the next character to upper case

> Expected Output:

**The Sky is Blue**

My code works fine but, I was wondering if it can be done in a more pythonic way.

```
for i in range (len(tmp)):
    if (tmp[i]=='*' and tmp[i+1]=='*') or (tmp[i]=='*' and tmp[i+1]=='/') or (tmp[i]=='/' and tmp[i+1]=='*') or (tmp[i]=='/' and tmp[i+1]=='/'):
        tmp[i+2]=tmp[i+2].upper()

        tmp[i]=""
        tmp[i+1]=" "
        res.append(tmp)
    elif (tmp[i]=='*' or tmp[i]=='/'):
        tmp[i]=" "
        res.append(tmp)
    else:
        res.append(tmp)
new_sentence = ''.join(res[1])
```

Comment: your list is no python. Please fix this to a [mcve]

Comment: list comprehension

Comment: You say you have working code. If you want it to be more pythonic, consider reading about list comprehensions and/or regex  - both would lead to cleaner code. It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: Also even if the list was right there is only one '/' before apple, why do you transform it into uppercase?

Comment: I apologize, I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pythonic way of what you are asking is very simple and just a single line:

```
tmp = ['a', 'n', '*', '*', ...]
result = "".join(tmp).replace('**', ' ').replace('//', ' ').title().replace('*', ' ').replace('/', ' ').replace('  ', ' ')
```

Multiple replaces based on the conditions that you required to be replaced

Editing the answer based on the update in question. In order to replace occurrence of a `*` and a `/` with space:

```
import re
tmp_string = "".join(tmp)
result = re.sub(r'[\*|/]{2}', ' ', tmp_string)
result = result.title().replace('*', ' ').replace('/', ' ').replace('  ', ' ')
```

Comment: The code is really efficient and i got to learn something new. Thanks. However, when used on the list: tmp = ['T', 'h', 'e', '/', '*', 's', 'k', 'y', '*', 'i', 's', '/', '/', 'b', 'l', 'u', 'e'], It capitalises 'I' of 'is' also which isnt required, how can this be avoided?

Comment: @HackersInside The empty string as a list element is not mentioned in your question's requirements. Please update them properly so that I can edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your `if` a little like this:

```
forbidden = '*/'
for i in range (len(tmp)):
    if tmp[i] and tmp[i+1] in forbidden:
        # do what you want
    elif tmp[i] in forbidden and tmp[i+1] not in forbidden:
        # do what you want
    else:
        # do what you want
```